# Porque não Filtra o Select Like na Pagina Php em MySql

Tags: php

Olá estou com o mesmo problema na minha table da base de dados onde existe o campo diasemana

alguns registros estão com os seguintes dados no campo diasemana = Segunda Terça Quarta Quinta Sexta

e outros diasemana = Terça Quinta, outros diasemana = Segunda, outros só Quarta

No PhpMyAdmin quando eu coloco a Linha de comando

```
Select * from grade Where diasemana Like '%Segunda%';
```

Ele retorna corretamente

Porém na minha pagina php aonde esta o script abaixo de paginação

```
 //verifica a página atual caso seja informada na URL, senão atribui como 1ª página
    $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;

    //$diasemana = trim(strip_tags($_GET['diasemana']));
    #$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM produtos");

$diasemana = trim(strip_tags("Terça"));


//seleciona todos os itens da tabela
$cmd = "Select * from table Where diasemana Like '%".$diasemana."%'";

try {

        $query = $pdo->prepare($cmd);
        $query->execute();


//conta o total de itens
   $total = $query->rowCount();

   //echo $total;

//seta a quantidade de itens por página, neste caso, 2 itens
$registros = 20;

//calcula o número de páginas arredondando o resultado para cima
$numPaginas = ceil($total/$registros);

//variavel para calcular o início da visualização com base na página atual
 $inicio = ($registros*$pagina)-$registros;

 //seleciona os itens por página (segunda query sobrepondo a anterior
 $cmd = "select * from table limit $inicio,$registros";
 $query = $pdo->prepare($cmd);
 $query->execute();

 //reconta o total de itens
   $total = $query->rowCount();



#while($linha = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ 




?>
```

Bem em resumo - na Pagina Php lado do servidor ele não está filtrando o que pode estar ocorrendo se alguem puder mi dar um help desde já agradeço

Answer (score 0):

Seu SELECT na linha de comando está diferente do SELECT no PHP:

```
$cmd = "Select * from table Where diasemana Like '%".$diasemana."%'";

Select * from grade Where diasemana Like '%Segunda%';
```

Baseado nisso, o certo seria:

```
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM grade WHERE diasemana LIKE '%".$diasemana."%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá Renan primeiramente obrigado mas eu só coloquei table e esqueci só para não mostrar o nome da table mas mesmo em grade não retorna a consulta seria a versão do Msql Pdo de eu não estar usando o MySqli?